# Geoserver: Write-back to Database?

Tags: geoserver

We serve maps as a service to internal users (named users within a domain) via geoserver. Maps are used within a browser, i.e. leaflet.

Is there a way to write back data from the user via geoserver to any "data source"? If not: Is there an easy way? We only need to save some unformatted text with reference to the map (coordinates) + time and name of user. And we need to use the browser - QGIS is no option.

Comment: What you want is wfs-t, you'll need to give users write permission to the layer(s) they can edit.